# Get linear distribution on jqplot line chart ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot, linechart

I would like to provide `tickInterval` on jqPlot chart renderer to get linear distribution on xaxis.

```
 $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    var chartData = [[1, 224], [3, 672], [5, 1120],[15,2240]];

    function PlotChart(chartData) {


    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [chartData], {
        title: 'Mouse Cursor Tracking',
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                smooth: true
            },
            pointLabels: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                label: 'Number of Cookies',
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                // renderer to use to draw the axis,     
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '%d'
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                label: 'Calories',
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '%.2f'
                }
            }
        },
        highlighter: {
            sizeAdjust: 7.5
        },
        cursor: {
            show: true
        }
   });
} PlotChart(chartData);
```

[**jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jpatel/JDu5q/)

Above is an example of the chart how it currently look.
I would like to provide the points 1, 5, 10, 15, 20 on the `xaxis` (tickInterval - 5) and in relation to 1,3,5,15 plots needs to be in coordinate plane to map the values [[1, 224], [3, 672], [5, 1120],[15,2240]]

Where currently its distributed as per the `xticks` which is uneven. Any help is welcome!

I tried to get it using min/max and `tickInterval` property, but seems like its not coming up fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide tickIntervals on your x-axis then you can do it this way.

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
var chartData = [[1, 224], [3, 672], [5, 1120],[15,2240]];

function PlotChart(chartData) {

var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [chartData], {
    title: 'Mouse Cursor Tracking',
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            smooth: true
        },
        pointLabels: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            label: 'Number of Cookies',
            min:0,
            max:20,
            tickInterval:5,
            // renderer to use to draw the axis,     
            tickOptions: {
                formatString: '%d'
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            label: 'Calories',
            tickOptions: {
                formatString: '%.2f'
            }
        }
    },
    highlighter: {
        sizeAdjust: 7.5
    },
    cursor: {
        show: true
    }
});
}
PlotChart(chartData);
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/n67Rw/)

You can calculate `min`, `max` and `tickInterval` before plotting the graph. 
I hope this helps.

Comment: Your code works fine. But looks like the jsFiddle link you provided is from my example, so it doesn't reflect the change. Here is the updated one - http://jsfiddle.net/jpatel/EWJLb/

Answer (score 0):

By **NOT** using `renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer` you'll get it going your way